# Nested Loops for a Higher/Lower Game

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

```
import random

seedVal = int(input("What seed should be used? "))
random.seed(seedVal)

while (True):
    lower = int(input("What is the lower bound? "))
    upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
    number = random.randint(min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper))

    if (lower >= upper):
        print("Lower bound must be less than upper bound.")

    else:
        guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        if (guess < number):
            print("Nope, too low.")

        elif (guess > number):
            print("Nope, too high.")

        elif (guess == number):
            print("You got it!")
            break

        else:
            print("Guess should be between lower bound and upper bound.")
```

This is my code so far for a higher/lower game I'm working on for my scripting class. The issue I run into when I test it is: the nested if/else statement goes back to the beginning of the while loop after an incorrect guess, such as "Nope, too low". I understand this is how a while loop works; However, I cannot figure out how to get the if/else statement to continue on without prompting the user for another lower/upper bound. My best guess is, obviously, to use a nested loop I just don't know how to in this situation.

Comment: You need two loops.  The first loop gets `lower` and `upper`, and asks the user to re-input them if they make a mistake, and breaks out of the loop if its happy.  The second loop plays the game with the given `lower` and `upper`.

Comment: Ahh, of course! I'm a noob didn't even think of the possibility of two separate loops. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a nested loop but just to get the set up of upper/lower in a different loop.

By the way, you will never get to the `else` at the end since you don't check if the value is within the bounds.

```
correct_boundaries = False
while not correct_boundaries:
    lower = int(input("What is the lower bound? "))
    upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
    if (lower >= upper):
        print("Lower bound must be less than upper bound.")
    else:
        number = random.randint(min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper))
        correct_boundaries = True


while (True):

        guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        if (guess < number):
            print("Nope, too low.")

        elif (guess > number):
            print("Nope, too high.")

        elif (guess == number):
            print("You got it!")
            break

        else:
            print("Guess should be between lower bound and upper bound.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Merely move them out of the loop

```
import random

seedVal = int(input("What seed should be used? "))
random.seed(seedVal)

lower = int(input("What is the lower bound? "))
upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
if (lower >= upper):
    raise ValueError("Lower bound must be less than upper bound.")

number = random.randint(min(lower, upper), max(lower, upper))

while (True):    
    guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
    if (guess < number):
        print("Nope, too low.")
    elif (guess > number):
        print("Nope, too high.")
    elif (guess == number):
        print("You got it!")
        break
    else:
        print("Guess should be between lower bound and upper bound.")
```